# In the movie Harry Potter and the Order or the Phoenix, why didn't Mr. Filch succeed to open the Room of Requirement if it's what he needed?

Tags: harry-potter

As stated by Dobby in *The Order of the Phoenix*

> ‘Because [the Room of Requirement] is a room that a person can only enter,’ said Dobby seriously, ‘when they have real need of it’
>
> > *Order of the Phoenix* - page 343 - Bloomsbury - chapter 18, "Dumbledore's Army"

And as stated in the question [Could a Muggle access to the Room of Requirement ?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26701/could-a-muggle-access-the-room-of-requirement), Muggles can have access to the Room of Requirement.

My question is, when in the movie, some students enter in the Room of Requirement and Filch follows them, the door changes little by little and Filch opens it to see some cleaning stuff. Why didn't the Room of Requirement stay still because what Filch needed the most is to find the students ?

Comment: Maybe because the students “*didn’t want to be found*”?

Comment: Apparently it can only be one thing at a time. So if someone's in there, it doesn't open up.

Comment: @Möoz But it doesn't have to be two different things, Filch wants the same room, the one with the student. And moreover, it opens as a second Room of Requirement with the cleaning stuff.

Comment: You do understand: Want != Need.

Comment: What about Filch's ... lousy prowess at magic?

Comment: Wasn't the wish of DA to "have a place where they can't be found"? I don't have any copy near me, but if that was the case, then RoR would be expected to treat wishes of people *inside* with higher priority than wishes of people *outside*.

Comment: Why is no one mentioning Harry’s attempts to find out what the room became for Draco Malfoy in book six?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As explained in Chapter Twenty-One of *Half-Blood Prince*, needing to catch someone using the room doesn’t work:

> “Dobby, have you managed to get in to have a look at what Malfoy’s doing?” said Harry eagerly.
>
> “No, Harry Potter, that is impossible,” said Dobby.
>
> “No, it’s not,” said Harry at once. “Malfoy got into our headquarters there last year, so I’ll be able to get in and spy on him, no problem.”
>
> “But I don’t think you will, Harry,” said Hermione slowly. “Malfoy already knew exactly how we were using the room, didn’t he, because that stupid Marietta had blabbed. He needed the room to become the headquarters of the D.A., so it did. But you don’t know what the room becomes when Malfoy goes in there, so you don’t know what to ask it to transform into.”

According to this, if Filch had been trying to get into the DA headquarters it would have worked, but simply trying to catch the students wouldn’t.

In fact, in the book version of *Order of the Phoenix*  (Chapter Twenty-Seven) Umbridge’s people did gain access to the headquarters:

> I have all their names here, Miss Parkinson ran into the Room of Requirement for me to see if they had left anything behind. . . . We needed evidence and the room provided . . .”

Comment: Looks like a good answer to me and consistent, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that Filch wants "the room that the students are in".  Now, if the students want Filch not to see them, then there is a conflict between the two.

However, if the Students just want the entrance to be blocked by a cupboard of cleaning supplies, then Filch can access the room without issue - however, there are walls blocking his view of the students:
[image: Image of a Room-within-a-Room (of Requirement)]

Like this, there is *technically* no conflict between the two requirements - both are fulfilled by one configuration.

Comment: What about the destruction of the door when the Army is caught ? If I remember correctly (which is not necessary the case) Umbrige destroy a door right ? Not a closet. Like the detail of the cat tho :)

Comment: @TinyDoowy Perhaps Umbridge wanted to actually *see* the students, not just the Room they were using?

Comment: Possibly because Umbridge had been briefed by a Dumbledore's army insider on the nature of the room, and knew what she had to do to overcome the obstacle.  She's also considerably smarter than Filch.

Comment: The cleaning supplies cupboard is what the Room of Requirement originally was. `'It's bizarre,' said Fred, frowning around at it. 'We once hid from Filch in here, remember, George? But it was just a broom cupboard then.'` I don't really see where you're getting this weird theory of the students putting a cleaning-supply closet there...

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath They needed a broom cupboard to hide from Filch in.  They found something that fitted their Requirement.  Likewise, when Dumbledore found it, it was a large room full of chamberpots.  Is *that* what it originally was?

Comment: @Chronocidal - That's a good point; I didn't think about that... But I still don't see where this theory is coming from!

Comment: Upvote for including Mrs. Norris the cat.