# Who was the first witch or wizard to find out Harry could produce a Patronus charm? (Besides Lupin)

Tags: harry-potter

Between *Prisoner of Azkaban* and *Order of the Phoenix*, does anyone find out that Harry can produce a Patronus? As a Squib, would Arabella Figg count? [**Squibs are not Muggles**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/is-a-squib-a-muggle) (but they're from Wizarding families).

Comment: Just to clear, are you asking about seeing his full corporeal Patronus, or just the standard version? Either way I think Richard has you covered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Book Series

It looks like Harry's first *casting* of a patronus was **in front of the entire school** during his Quidditch match:

> Distracted, Harry looked down.
>   Three Dementors, three tall, black, hooded Dementors, were looking up at him.
>   He didn’t stop to think. Plunging a hand down the neck of his robes, he whipped out his wand and roared, ‘Expecto patronum!’
>   Something silver white, something enormous, erupted from the end of his wand. He knew it had shot directly at the Dementors but didn’t pause to watch; his mind still miraculously clear, he looked ahead – he was nearly there. He stretched out the hand still grasping his wand and just managed to close his fingers over the small, struggling Snitch.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Prison of Azkaban: Chapter 13 - Gryffindor versus Ravenclaw</sup></sub>

That being said, Oliver Wood notes cryptically that Harry has a secret weapon against the Dementors. As Oriol points out in [his comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125541/who-was-the-first-witch-or-wizard-to-find-out-harry-could-produce-a-patronus-cha/125542?noredirect=1#comment313200_125542), they only spoke in terms of his "*warding off*" the dementors rather than specifically that he would be trying a Patronus but that then beggars the question of what other ways exist to ward off a Dementor if not the Patronus:

> ‘I can’t see what’s going to stop us tomorrow!’ said Wood. ‘Not unless – Harry, **you’ve sorted your Dementor problem, haven’t you?**’
>   ‘Yeah,’ said Harry, thinking of his feeble Patronus and wishing it was stronger.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Prison of Azkaban: Chapter 13 - Gryffindor versus Ravenclaw</sup></sub>

### Film Series

Within the films, the order of events is different. Harry gets knocked off his broom in the Quidditch match (never casting the Patronus) and only does so in front of Hermione toward the end of the film.

[image]

Comment: «*“I’m working on it,” said Harry quickly. “Professor Lupin said he’d train me to ward off the Dementors. We should be starting this week. He said he’d have time after Christmas.”*». So I think Wood knows Harry has some way to counteract dementors, but he doesn't (necessarily) know it's the patronus charm.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was watching the third task of the Triwizard Tournament, yes. Harry produced a patronus when he was faced with a Boggart of a Dementor. So in short yes!

Comment: I don't see how "yes" answers the question "who"...