# Could a wizard and witch have a Muggle child?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory, muggles, squib

We know Muggle parents can have a magical child, but could magical parents have a Muggle child?

Comment: They're known as squibs not muggles

Comment: In the dupe target the question being asked is actually *"Wizards can be born to Muggles. Can Muggles be born to wizards?"*

Comment: @Skooba - But the dupe (or rather your answer to it) does make it clear that squibs are born to wizards, not muggles. Which makes it a dupe

Answer (score 4):

### Depends what you mean by 'Muggle'.

A **Squib** is a person with no magical powers born to magical parents. They fall somewhere in between a wizard and a Muggle: while unable to actually perform magic, they can still access the magical world. From the [Pottermore fact file](https://www.pottermore.com/fact-file-creatures/squibs-factfile):

> Humans with little or no magical talent born into wizarding families, who are looked down on by the wizarding world
>
> Appearance: Usually dressed like the rest of wizard-kind
>
> Magic Abilities: Able to access the wizarding world, unlike Muggles, and can use certain magical objects and creatures

We even see a couple of these in the main HP stories: **Argus Filch**, the unpleasant janitor of Hogwarts, and **Arabella Figg**, the cat-loving neighbour of the Dursleys. But according to Ron, they're not very common:

> A Squib is someone who was born into a wizarding family but hasn’t got any magic powers. Kind of the opposite of Muggle-born wizards, but Squibs are quite unusual.
>
> <sub>-- Ron Weasley, *HP and the Chamber of Secrets*</sub>

See also [Is a Squib a Muggle?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14526/31394)

Comment: You could also provide the examples of Filch and Mrs. Figg

Comment: @Gallifreyan Done.

Comment: Q. If a squib was raised as a muggle, would they be a muggle? Answer. Not according to Graves in the new Fantastic Beasts film.

Comment: @Valorum: What do you mean? I thought the Fantastic Beasts film showed what happened to a wizard who was raised as a muggle, not a squib.