# Can we consider Squib-born wizards as Mudbloods?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles, squib

Dark wizards call muggle-born wizards as mudbloods because they promote racism. Voldemort and his allies repulsed of Muggles, giving them enough hatred for them to throw.

However, what do Voldemort and his allies call those Squib-born wizards? Can we also consider them as Mudbloods?

Comment: This can quickly lead into on of these ancestry-variant tables the Nazis made...

Comment: As opposed to the nice folk who call ordinary people "muggles" and magically challenged wizards "squibs" :}

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/is-a-squib-a-muggle is very relevant here.

Comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11140/why-cant-i-use-the-word-mudblood

Comment: @Fabian - You mean something like the "[Muggle Born Registration Commission](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Muggle-Born_Registration_Commission)"?

Answer (score 6):

First off, the wizards who call muggle-borns "mudbloods" are not full of wickedness in their minds like they are under some evil spell; They are simply evil hateful racist people bent on taking over and destroying everything good.

A muggle-born is a person with magical abilities born into a family of muggles, hence the name muggle-born: they are just like any other wizard or witch and they are not inferior to, or weaker then pure-blood witches and wizards.

They are referred to as mudbloods in a racist term as pure-bloods consider themselves superior because of their lineage.

A muggle-born is not handicapped in any way; in fact some purebloods may be more hindered then a muggle-born (because to maintain a pureblood family some incest may be required).

A squib is a "muggle" born into a family with one or more magically gifted parents. The books don't mention any other names that Voldemort and his gang use to refer to squibs.

A squib would not be considered a muggle-born because he or she would have to have at least one magically gifted parent and no magical ability to count as a squib where-as a muggle-born has both of his/her parents muggles and magical abilities

A child of a squib would either be a squib or a wizard/witch because of genetics. One of his parents was a squib so it doesn't matter if the child has the other parent as a muggle or a magical, the child still has the genetic potential to have that magical ability.

Just because the parent is a squib does not mean that the genetic trait (or lack of) that allows magic isn't there. It would be passed down to his or her children giving them the ability to have magic. (Or not, it depends on what genetic traits dominate.)

According to [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/is-a-squib-a-muggle?noredirect=1&lq=1) a squib is not a muggle, and for a muggle-born to occur both parents would need to be muggles. So a child of a squib would either be a half-blood or a pure-blood (depending on the parents).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, whereas Muggle-born magical people serve as a metaphor for racism, Squibs serve as a metaphor for disability. This would mean that Squibs are not equivalent to Muggles and therefore that wizards and witches born to Squibs are not Muggle-born (and those born to a witch or wizard and a Squib are not half-blood). That being said, I would assume that many bigoted racist people would also be ableist and would therefore discriminate Squib-born witches and wizards as well. (tl;dr I agree with your conclusion, just adding my 2 cents)

Comment: very well said, as I stated a squib wouldnt be a muggle-born as he/she has one or more magically gifted parents and just missed out on the magical genes a muggle-born is a wizard that has muggles as both parents (and probably a wizard/witch in the family some place)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, it just restates the definitions of squib and muggle. The question is about the children of squibs.

Comment: the question is not clear. A child of a squib with magical abilities would be  either a pure-blood (with a squib and a magical) or half-blood (a squib with a muggle) because [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/is-a-squib-a-muggle?noredirect=1&lq=1) a squib is not a wizard, a squib is simply a "wizard" lacking the magical ability

Comment: I edited the end of my answer to better answer his question

Comment: @E.Huckabee if I'm not mistaken, we can only consider someone as half blood if he or she is a half of muggle and wizard's blood. Whereas, the pure blood only pertains to two wizards.

Comment: a squib is not a muggle, the only other "classification" is wizard. A squib has the genetic trait that makes him a wizard, it just didnt dominate during development in the womb so the child of a squib (with a wizard/witch) would either be a squib or a wizard if the child is a magical he/she is pureblood in all senses of the term. However with a muggle as the second parent the child would be a squib a muggle or a wizard (like I stated its all in the genetics) if the child is a magical he/she is halfblood

Comment: Agreed. "Mudblood" is a slur based on a wizard or witch's ancestry (their "impure" blood). I guess a pureblood fanatic would refer to a squib born to Muggleborn parents (or one Muggleborn parent) as a "Mudblood" but that would be because of their parentage, not their lack of magic powers.